# How to debug QFixed in visual studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013

QFixed is used in many internal struct inside qt source code. visual studio is one of the best c++ debugger.

QFixed raw view is an integer which is multiplied by 64, how could I view the divied-by-64 value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. open `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\Packages\Debugger\Visualizers\qt5.natvis`.
2. add

[image]

3. result
   [image]